# Why is this Robot code to take a screenshot not working when the computer is locked?

Tags: java, screenshot, awtrobot

I am using the Robot class to take a screenshot of the desktop:

```
Robot objRobot = null;
try {
    objRobot = new Robot();
} catch(Exception ex) {
}
BufferedImage objBufferedImage =  objRobot.createScreenCapture(objRectArea);
```

The problem is that when my computer is locked the image comes up as black. That is, what is displayed on the desktop is not captured. I want the screenshot to display the desktop even when my computer is locked. How can I do this? I would prefer a solution that still uses Robot.

Comment: Sagar, You're EATING an exception!!! Any co-op who eats an exception in my codebase gets flogged... well, no, not really... they just get a talking to, and then made to fix every single occurence in the whole base (at that time). It's a tedious and boring task, and nobody's ever done it twice. With that fixed you just MIGHT have an idea of why Robot fails when the PC is locked. My money is on "it's a security precaution", but I don't know off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public class Main {

        private Robot robot = new Robot();

        public Main() throws AWTException, IOException {
            int x = 800;
            int y = 800;
            int width = 200;
            int height = 200;
            imageCapture(x, y, width, height);
    }


        private void imageCapture(int x, int y, int width, int height) throws IOException {
            Rectangle area = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(area);
            //remove next line if u do not want file.png saved
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("file.png"));
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException {
            new Main();
        }/**
         * @return the robot
         */
        public Robot getRobot() {
            return robot;
        }

        /**
         * @param robot the robot to set
         */
        public void setRobot(Robot robot) {
            this.robot = robot;
        }


    }
```

Makes file.png in project too